# Как создать ночь в unity2D?

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть свет (типо солнце, я использовал Hard Light 2D). Я сделал анимацию которая двигает этот свет. Но даже если его удалить, "ночью" все прекрасно видно. А мне нужно чтобы при удалении или перемещении света на уровне становилось реально темно, а не нормально.

Comment: Попробуй intensity на 0 поставить либо color сделать прозрачным. В гугле много инфы по этой теме, так что если не поможет, поищи там

Answer (score 2):

## Освещение сцены

- Окно настройки: `Window`/`Rendering`/`Lighting`
- Вкладка: `Environment`

---

Сцена без `Direction Light`, `Spot Light` единственный источник.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### `Environment Lighting`

Если тип `Skybox`, то поле `IntencivityMultiplayer` выставленное на 0 убирает небо как источник света. Если `Skybox Material` отсутствует, то и источника света нет, вместо него `Ambiant Color`.

Если тип `Solid Color`, то поле `Ambiant Color` и за интенсивность отвечает `Value` (`V`) в цветовой схеме `HSV`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### `Environment Reflections`

Последним источником является отражения, поле `IntencivityMultiplayer`. Если `Sun Source` отсутствует, то отражать нечего.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Так-же все зависит от материалов. Например `Mobile/VertexLit` в отличие от `Standart` ничего не отражает, сделать его абсолютно черным можно только через `Environment Lighting`/`Solid Color`.

---

Настраивается все это веселие через скрипт с помощью [RenderSettings](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderSettings.html).

Comment: У меня 2д игра. В Unity 2D даже если просто поставить спрайт его уже будет нормально видно. А мне нужно это освещение из проекта убавить